# c# ASP.NET - No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44301/swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

I have added this to **program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
 builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

 var app = builder.Build();
 if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
 {
     app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
     {
         c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
         c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
     });
 }
 app.Run();
```

I have added this to the configure part of **startup.cs**

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Quanta 5 API"));
}

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/", context =>
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/swagger/");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

I got this error:

> This localhost page can’t be found
>
> No webpage was found for the web address:
> https://localhost:44301/swagger

what can I do to fix this error?

Comment: .NET 6 and later don't use `Startup.cs`.

Comment: check url without "swagger" https://localhost:44301/, remove startup.cs - not in use, and schema would be in http://localhost:5198/swagger/v1/swagger.json

Comment: Try using this end point: `c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Quanta 5 API"));`